# CreateFileA fails with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED

Tags: c, winapi

I need to retrieve a handle to a directory to be able to call **[ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** on it. Actually I would need a bit more than that but let’s go easy first. I have narrowed down the problem to this:

```
m_directoryHandle = CreateFileA(
    "C:\\Users\\victor\\Documents\\Projets\\libxnotify\\unittests", // __in      LPCTSTR lpFileName,
    FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,    // __in      DWORD dwDesiredAccess,
    0,                      // __in      DWORD dwShareMode,
    0,                      // __in_opt  LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpSecurityAttributes,
    OPEN_EXISTING,          // __in      DWORD dwCreationDisposition,
    0,                      // __in      DWORD dwFlagsAndAttributes,
    0                       // __in_opt  HANDLE hTemplateFile
);
```

This return an `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` with a last error code of `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. Needless to say, I have tried oodles of different parameters, none on them did work. I run my program as victor, and to make sure I really had the rights in that unittests directory, I opened a command shell and typed:

`C:\Users\victor>echo bla >> "C:\Users\victor\Documents\Projets\libxnotify\unittests\test"`

and it worked.

Comment: Do you, perhaps, have to specify the filename (together with the path) in the first parameter? `C:\\Users...unittests\\filename.txt`

Comment: @pmg Hm, I have incorrectly stated my question. I really need to have an handle on the directory, to be able to call `ReadDirectoryChangesW` on it (and monitor files)..

Comment: `0` for `dwShareMode`? This is where it might be failing, as you request a sort of exclusive access handle...

Comment: @RomanR I will give a couple tries with other parameters and let you know.

Comment: [Quoted from msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365258%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): "To obtain a handle to an existing directory, call the **[CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx)** function with the **FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS** flag."

Comment: @RomanR well it did not work, but the other remarks did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465(v=vs.85).aspx) has a remark that states:

> To obtain a handle to a directory, use the `CreateFile` function with the **FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS** flag.

The documentation for [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) then also has a more detailed remark about this:

> **Directories**
>
> An application cannot create a directory by using `CreateFile`, therefore only the **OPEN_EXISTING** value is valid for dwCreationDisposition for this use case. To create a directory, the application must call `CreateDirectory` or `CreateDirectoryEx`.
>
> To open a directory using `CreateFile`, specify the **FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS** flag as part of `dwFlagsAndAttributes`. Appropriate security checks still apply when this flag is used without **SE_BACKUP_NAME** and **SE_RESTORE_NAME** privileges.

You're missing out on this important `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` flag for `dwFlagsAndAttributes`.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Now why don’t they put their flag themselves if it is compulsory for a directory…

Comment: @qdii: The Windows API is always fun to use. I'd also probably use `FILE_SHARE_READ` for `dwShareMode` as opposed to 0.